# Read from file a sparse-matrix

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix

I'm using a the Yale representation of sparse-matrix in power iteration algorithm, everything goes well and fast.

But, now I have a problem, my professor will send the sparse-matrix in a data file unordered, and since the matrix is symmetric only one pair of index will be there.

The problem is, in my implementation I need to insert the elements in order.

I tried somethings to  read and after that insert into my sparse-matrix:

1) Using a dense matrix.

2) Using another sparse-matrix implementation, I tried with std::map.

3) Priority queue, I made a array of priority_queues. I insert the element i,j in the priority_queue[i], so when I pop the priority_queue[i] I take the lowest j-index of the row i.

But I need something really fast and memory efficient, because the largest matrix I'll use will be like 100k x 100k, and the tries I made was so slow, almost 200 times slower than the power iteration itself.

Any suggestions? Sorry for the poor english :(

Comment: What about reading the data as he sent it and then reformatting it to you format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way many sparse loaders work is that you use an intermediate pure triples structure. I.e. whatever the file looks like, you load it into something like `vector< tuple< row, column, value> >`.

You then build the sparse structure from *that*. The reason is precisely what you're running into. Your sparse matrix structure likely has constraints, like you need to know the number of elements in each row/column, or the input needs to be sorted, etc. You can massage your triples array into whatever you need (i.e. by sorting it).

This also makes it trivial to solve your symmetry dilemma. For every triple in the source file, you insert both `(row, column, value)` and `(column, row, value)` into your intermediate structure.

Another option is to simply write a script that will sort your professor's file.

FYI, in the sparse world the number of elements (nonzeros) is what matters, not the dimensions of the matrix. `100k-by-100k` is a meaningless piece of information. That entire matrix could be totally empty, for example.